PyInstaller unable to find data file (db.sqlite) during packaging in `.spec` file
I'm working on packaging a Python project using PyInstaller. My project includes a db.sqlite file, which I need to include in the final executable. I’m using a .spec file to package the application, but I keep getting an error saying that the db.sqlite file cannot be found, even though it's in the specified directory.
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

a = Analysis(
    ['gui.py'],
    pathex=['D:\\Programming\\Projects\\Library_Management'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[(r'D:\Programming\Projects\Library_Management\assets\db.sqlite', 'assets')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='gui',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)

When I run pyinstaller gui.spec, I get this error:
Unable to find 'D:\\Programming\\Projects\\Library_Management\\assets\\db.sqlite' when adding binary and data files.

I verified that the db.sqlite file is located in my specified path (D:\\Programming\\Projects\\Library_Management\\assets\\db.sqlite). I also tried adjusting the path in the .spec file and rebuilding, but I still getting the same error.
What's the reason that PyInstaller to not finding the db.sqlite file, and how can I fix this issue?

Cannot reproduce the issue with duplicating the path same as yours.

It definitely has something to do with the path to your sqlite file.
Try changing them to regular slashes instead of backslashes, or use the relative path instead of absolute to see if that works.
Have you tried running pyinstaller on a minimal project just to verify that it works without any assets etc?
